# Lerna hoist does not work with folders that are not siblings or inside the packages folder.

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, lerna

I am using lerna, and am using it to `npm install` and `build` our angular code. But my projects cannot go into the packages folder.

I want to let lerna npm install a bunch of different projects, [hoisting](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/master/doc/hoist.md) common dependencies, then run build on all of them. Here is my directory structure:

```
c:/myproject/lerna/lerna.json
c:/myproject/Core/App1/package.json
c:/myproject/Core/App2/package.json
c:/myproject/Core/App3/package.json
```

my lerna.json references those packages.

```
"packages": [
   "../Core/App1",
   "../Core/App2",
   "../Core/App3",
]
```

This does not work because the `node_modules` folder is not in the parent folder. Its in the 'aunt' folder. **How can I add the hoisted dependencies in `lerna/node_modules` even though they are not in a parent folder.**